# Why is it called Winter Bash?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

OK, it is winter, but we don't bash anything. So why is it called Winter Bash?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about English.

Comment: @nicael I don't understand

Comment: zsh is much better than bash. Next year it should be Winter zsh.

Comment: Mark, it's the question not about Stack Exchange, but about the meaning of the word *bash*.

Comment: @nicael - nope, it is about the reason a specific name was chosen for a network wide event. The fact that the reason is not some obscure wordplay, reference to a meme or other joke but instead just a meaning of the word the topic creator didn't think about doesn't seem to make this OT imho. Maybe you can downvote for lack of research if you feel grinchy enough, but to actually close as OT seems a little stretched.

Comment: It's not winter in Australia....

Comment: @Derpy not only didn't think about, but didn't know about.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From dictionary.com, [bash](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bash):

> noun
>
> 3. a crushing blow.
> 4. Informal. a thoroughly enjoyable, lively party.

Meaning 4 is why WinterBash is named so.

Comment: So I didn't have to punch all those people ... brb, I have some apologies to make.

Comment: For a pair of glasses, you sure like living dangerously...

Answer (score 5):

There are several meaning of bash

[Bash meaning](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=bash%20meaning&oq=bash%20meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57.2375j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

> a party or social event. "a birthday bash"

It is likely to be a slang way to call it explained [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48653/bash-vs-party) well.